# Insert SQL Command with dynamic Username and rowtypes

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, execute-immediate

I'd like to generate a dynamic Insert statement with different Username and data from a rowtype

My snippet

```
create or replace procedure test()
is
TYPE cv_typ is REF CURSOR;
cv cv_typ;
stmt varchar(2000);
zieldb varchar(20);

vKunden "Kunden"%rowtype;

BEGIN

execute immediate 'select * from "Kunden" where "KndNr"=55 ' into vKunden;

stmt:='select kc.zieldb from test.kunden_copy kc, test.transrel vd 
where kc.zieldb=vd.dbname and kc.status=1 ';

OPEN cv FOR stmt;
LOOP
    FETCH cv into nachdb;
    EXIT WHEN cv%NOTFOUND;
    ...
    ...
    stmt:='insert into ' || nachdb || ' ."Kunden"   values  ' || vKunden;
    execute immediate stmt ;        
    ...
    ... 
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the following error message:

Please-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call

With the following syntax

```
stmt:='insert into ' || nachdb || ' ."Kunden"   values   vKunden ';
execute immediate stmt ;
```

I get the following message:

ORA-03001: unimplemented feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't do that. In your first attempt you're trying to concatenate a PL/SQL record type (from the `%rowtype`) onto a string; if it let you then what would it put, its internal representation of the the record? For it to be a valid insert statement it would have to translate it into a list of values from the record, as `(col1, col2, ...)`, which is asking quite a lot of it.

In your second version, with the ORA-03001, I think that's because it's interpreting `vKunden` as an object identifier; the record variable in the PL/SQL block isn't in scope in the SQL statement.

Presumably you've tried using a bind variable for this, and discovered that you can't, because bind variables have to be SQL types (PLS-00457).

You could perhaps use `DBMS_SQL` to step through the `%rowtype` variable and build up your own `values` clause based on the columns/fields it contains, but that seems painful.

Presumably though the various versions of `"Kunden"` (quoted object identifiers? don't you find that very painful to work with?) are all identical, otherwise the `%rowtype` you're using to declare `vKunden` wouldn't apply for the insert anyway, and so you know all the column names. You would have to bind each column value individually:

```
stmt:='insert into ' || nachdb || ' ."Kunden" ("KndNr", "Col2", ...)'
    || ' values (:1, :2, ...)';
execute immediate stmt using vKunden."KndNR", vKunden."Col2", ...;
```

Although even simpler would be:

```
stmt:='insert into ' || nachdb || ' ."Kunden"'
    || ' select * from "Kunden" where "KndNr"=55';
execute immediate stmt;
```

... which bypasses `vKunden` and the `%rowtype` issue altogether. You're doing that select multiple times, but that's might not be a significant amount of overhead

Answer (score 0):

Just to add why it won't work: The 03001 is because you don't have brackets () around the values. Even with brackets it won't work, because vKunden is of %rowtype, so you cannot pass this into a dynamic sql (pls-00457). You can check this by using: execute immediate 'select :1 from dual' using vKunden;